# echo php is converting to ascii

Tags: php, hex, ascii, echo

I am running a socket test in my server, it is working okay
I have a problem when I print the data, I think.

1) I read the packet from the client using this:

`$input = socket_read($client, 1024);`

2) then I echo/print to my terminal the input packet using this:

`echo $input;`

Question:

- Why when I send a binary packet like this `333536333037303432343431303133` I received a echo in terminal like ASCII representation `356307042441013`
- How to print the original format `333536333037303432343431303133` to my debian 10 terminal

SOLUTION:
`echo bin2hex($input);`

Comment: `var_dump($input)` gives `333536333037303432343431303133` but `echo $input;` gives `356307042441013`?

Comment: var_dump() doesnt show anything